# YouTube API with Internal app is forcing video's to go private (locked)

Tags: youtube-api

As the title says, I am using a internal app which clearly states that it does not require an audit from YouTube.

I use this to upload video's to my YouTube channel. After uploading, whenever I try to change the permissions from "private" to "hidden", YouTube automatically will set it to "private (locked)".

Does anyone know how I can get this working? all I want to do is:

1. Login by using oAuth2 on the (internal) app with an account that is within the internal workspace.
2. Upload clips to YouTube.
3. View the clips to the public on my website.

As said, we made an internal app and the account that uploads the movies is a member of the (internal) Google workspace.

Been trying to get this working for days now without any progress.

YouTube's documentation states that an internal app does not need an audit and therefor I would think that YouTube video's would be able to set public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)  documentation you will notice it states that app needs to be verified.

[image]

There was some note that if it was for internal use you did not need to be verified in practice this is not the case. Apply for verification and tell them its internal only should get you though the verification process quickly enough.